# Byte Array won't insert into PostgreSQL database using PDO PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, arrays

I'm trying to insert a picture into a PostGreSQL database using php and pdo. Here is my code :

```
<?php
try{

    $ndb=$_GET["db"];
    $user=$_GET["login"];
    $password=$_GET["pw"];
    $db = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=$ndb", $user, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $file_name = "wallabi.jpg";
    $data = file_get_contents($file_name);
    $es_data = bin2hex($data);
    $query = ("INSERT INTO images_preview VALUES (11, 2, 500, '2012-05-03','','', decode('{$es_data}', 'hex'))");
    print_r($query);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    print_r($stmt->execute());
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo '{"results":[{"error":'.$e.'}]}';
}
?>
```

I'm sure that :

- The problem doesn't come from the file
- The encoding is right because when I try to insert directly the field from my db interface, it works
- Something is wrong with the way it inserts using pdo

No errors are returned, or catched. The pdo states returns that the insertion was done well...
Please help me <3

Comment: Is nothing imported or just not the image?

Comment: Nothing... From the php, but when I copy the query and try to insert from the database interface, it works perfectly.. I'm missing something..

Comment: sorry i putted wrong one. please try this:- `$query = ("INSERT INTO images_preview VALUES (11, 2, 500, '2012-05-03','','', decode('".$es_data."', 'hex'))");`

Comment: Nop, not a quote mistake.. But though, when I print_r($stmt->execute()); , it returns 1, It means its good right?

Comment: Does it display anything if you do `$stmt->errorInfo();` after the `prepare` statement?

Comment: It displays : Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )
I'm not sure what it could mean ^^

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I used pgsql connection tools instead of pdo and it works good :

```
<?php
$ndb=$_GET["db"];
$user=$_GET["login"];
$password=$_GET["pw"];
$dbconn3 = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=$ndb user=$user password=$password");
$file_name = "wallabi.jpg";
$data = file_get_contents($file_name);
$es_data = pg_escape_bytea($data);
pg_query("INSERT INTO images_preview VALUES (11, 2, 500, '2012-05-03','','', '{$es_data}')");
?>
```